# Which truck has the highest HP?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I don't want to look through every truck dealer, so I was wondering which truck has the highest stock HP in the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Scania R730**, with 730 horsepower, is the highest. It is unlocked at level 25 and you can buy it in Milano (Italy), Hannover (Germany) or Manchester (England) for 212.430 Euros.

Answer (score 8):

The **Volvo F16H** (750 HP) have the highest HP. you will find it in Volvo's big showroom......its a heavy duty truck, but not the fastest, if you are looking for fast truck, you should take the **Scania R730**.

Comment: Given as another answer lists the Scania R730 as having the highest, it might be helpful to show that the Valiant F16H has more stock HP by also listing the stock HP of the Scania R730.